# What is that circle that replaces the WIFI icon on my iPhone 2G sometimes?

Tags: iphone

It's probably the phone's way of showing me there is no WIFI connection. Is that it? Probably not since that would probably be a "no icon" thing.

Anyway, couldn't find it in the user's manual so here you go... question asked.

Thx

Answer (score 16):

The circle indicates that you're [on the cellular GPRS data network](http://www.tuaw.com/2009/06/05/dear-auntie-tuaw-whats-that-little-dot-in-the-iphones-status/). The fact that it's visible also means that you don't have a wifi connection:

[image]

Comment: 3G/3GS/4’s show a “E” instead of that, to indicate that they are on “E”dge network.

Comment: @Martin: those newer models also show the circle if they are on plain GPRS without EDGE.